# assigning an array of strings to another one

Tags: c, string, parsing, malloc, arrayofstring

I'm trying to parse a C array of strings, assigning a part of the words to one array of strings, and the other part to another array. But when I use the strcpy function, I get segfault. Any idea how to solve this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])  {
    char **one = malloc(16 * sizeof(char*));
    char **two = malloc(32 * sizeof(char*));

    one[0] = "string";

    strcpy(two[0], one[0]);

    printf("%s\n", two[0]);
}
```

as a result of compiling and running this, I get segfault.

Comment: You need to allocate *an array of char* to `two[0]` too.

Comment: *"I get segfault. Any idea how to solve this?"* - That question **always** leads to one consistent troubleshooting method: run your program in a *debugger*.  The code-problem in this case is simple enough, but the overlaying theme of your question covers a lot more than just this simple problem.

Comment: You can also do `two[0] = one[0]` which doesn't copy the characters, but sets `two[0]` to a valid address.

Comment: @WhozCraig You're right, though I did run it in gdb and I read the man page of strcpy, the only thing I found was that the destination should be larger than the source. But I can say I'm not experienced in programming so that plays a role as well.

Comment: @sercantor Excellent that you used your debugger. In the future, any debugging efforts you've undertaken, and the information you've learned/concluded thus far, should be part of your question. It's important. It saves people time. In this case, not really so much, as the answer is glaringly simple. But in more complicated code it can be very helpful. Try and remember that for future posts.

Comment: @WhozCraig You're right again, the question I asked is kind of vague. I was writing a command line interpreter/shell but I had a problem parsing the string, so I  thought of simplifying it here and asking, but I guess because it's vague, it makes it even harder. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array `two` holds space for 32 character pointers after the `malloc`.
However, these pointers are uninitialized and do not point to valid allocated memory at this point.

Therefore, the `strcpy` essentially has a destination (`two[0]`) which is some unknown, uninitialized value. A pointer is essentially a value stored in memory. In this case, the value is grabage.

The write to a garbage address by `strcpy` generates a SEGFAULT due to the illegal memory access.

To resolve this, make sure that the destination (`two[0]`) points to a legitimate, writable buffer (perhaps `two[0] = malloc(128 * sizeof(char))`).

On a related note, look up the similar (but safer) function `strncpy`.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, this explains my question perfectly.